# RDLC report not recognizing inherited interface members when a child interface is set as a dataset

Tags: c#, inheritance, reporting-services, interface, rdlc

Say I have these two interfaces

```
interface IParentBusinessObject
{
    string Property1 { get; }
    string Property2 { get; }
}

interface IChildBusinessObject : IParentBusinessObject
{
    int Property3 { get; }
    string Proeprty4 { get; }
}
```

If I try to set up `IChildBusinessObject` as a dataset through the Visual Studio 2013 Report Wizard, it will recognize the members `Property3` and `Property4`, but it will not recognize the inherited members `Property1` and `Property2`. When setting up the dataset, I make sure that all interfaces in the inheritance hierarchy are available to choose from. For example, I could choose `IParentBusinessObject` as one dataset to report on `Property1` and `Property2`, or I can choose `IChildBusinessObject` and report on only `Property3` and `Property4`.

Some other information that may be important

- All of the interfaces and classes for my datasets are located in a separate assembly than my reports.
- When I use a concrete class as a dataset instead of an interface I can see all members, including inherited ones.
- When using an interface as a dataset, only members that are `System` types are recognized. All of my types I've defined do not show up. (Again, not a problem with concrete classes).
- If I setup the report with an interface as the dataset, then try to type out what should be expressions to get an inherited property, errors are thrown. (Expression Example: `=Fields!Property1.Value`)

Does anyone know how I can make these RDLC reports recognize my interface members in full?

Just using a concrete class as my dataset fixes this. However, I would like to avoid exposing my concrete types to outside assemblies if at all possible. Up until this point my code has worked great just operating off the interfaces, and I don't want to expose these business objects to outside code, even with `InternalsVisisbleTo`, just to accommodate this reporting software.